# Use Field_A value to find records based on a modified version of Field_A value on the same field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table, and I want to get the desired result set, based on :

1. Replace CS with C1 in "TICKER" and Replace CG with C2 in "TICKER".
2. Use above Ticker to find an exact match in TICKER field in the same table.
3. If there is a match, return the pair of records.

Existing Table:

```
TICKER | EXCHANGE | COUNTRY
-------+----------+--------
123 CS | HKE      | HK      
123 C1 | SGX      | SG
124 CG | LSE      | GB
124 C2 | NYE      | US
125 CS | NAS      | US
125 C1 | SGX      | SG
126 C1 | KUL      | MY
```

Desired result set:

```
TICKER | EXCHANGE | COUNTRY
-------+----------+--------
123 CS | HKE      | HK     
123 C1 | SGX      | SG
124 CG | LSE      | GB
124 C2 | NYE      | US
125 CS | NAS      | US
125 C1 | SGX      | SG
```

Appreciate your help on how to use the "C1/C2 ticker" to find an exact match so as to return the pair ?

thanks

Comment: I think I see four columns: 123 | CS | HKE | HK. But I only see three column names: TICKER | EXCHANGE | COUNTRY. Can you please clarify?

Comment: hi, i have " " the values... basically "123 CS" is a TICKER value!

Comment: if `Replace CS with C1 in "TICKER" and Replace CG with C2 in "TICKER"`, then why `CS` and  `CG` are still in desired result ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, perhaps "replace" is not the right word. what i wanted is to find the record where there is an associated record with "XXX C1" for another record with a  "XXX CS"  ticker. Return me the two records.

Comment: On a sidenote: As you are obviously interested in the separate parts of a ticker, you should *store*  them separately (i.e. in two separate columns) in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `COUNT OVER`:

```
select ticker, exchange, country
from
(
    select
        ticker, exchange, country,
        count(*) over (partition by 
                       regexp_substr(ticker, '^[^ ]+'), 
                       case when ticker like '%C1' 
                              or ticker like '%CS' then 'C1' else 'C2' end
                      ) as cnt
    from tickers
    where ticker like '%C1'
       or ticker like '%C2' 
       or ticker like '%CG' 
       or ticker like '%CS' 
)
where cnt > 1
order by ticker;
```

The inner `WHERE` clause can be replaced by the more elegant

```
regexp_like(ticker, '.*C[12GS]$')
```

by the way, if you prefer so.

The `CASE` expression can be replaced by

```
case when regexp_substr(ticker, '[^ ]+$') in ('C1', 'CS') then 'C1' else 'C2' end
```

or

```
case when regexp_like(ticker, '.*C[12]$') then 'C1' else 'C2' end
```

As mentioned in the comments, you may prefer to change your table design such as to have the ticker values separated. If you are not allowed to do so, you may still create a view with `regexp_substr(ticker, '^[^ ]+')` and `regexp_substr(ticker, '[^ ]+$')` and use this for convenience.

Comment: Hi for the below portion: I understand it will evalulate to : count(*) over partition by "123", "C1") as cnt.  My question is grouping by "123" and "c1" possible?    `count(*) over (partition by 
                       regexp_substr(ticker, '^[^ ]+'), 
                       case when ticker like '%C1' 
                              or ticker like '%CS' then 'C1' else 'C2' end
                      ) as cnt`

Comment: Why shouldn't this be possible? We are grouping by two parts: the first ticker part (123, 124, etc.) and a second part (with only either 'C1' or 'C2'). Why do you ask? Do you have issues with the query?

Comment: my qn is if the function group the entire result set of tickers_table by "first part of ticker", then how does it group by the second part of the same ticker ? cannot visualize the steps leading from grouping the first part of ticker to grouping to second art of ticker

Comment: Hm, kind of hard to guess what you are having problems with. The partition means I consider certain records a group to look at. If I used `partition by ticker` I would consider '123 CS' one group. There is only one such record, so I'd count 1. If I'd partition by the two parts instead, i.e. '123' and 'CS' I'd get the same result of course, as again there is one record matching this group.

Comment: I, however, partition by the first part plus a modified second part where 'C1' and 'C2' are treated the same value. So I find two records now for '123 C1|CS'. Both records '123 C1' and '123 CS' get the same group count 2. As their count is greater than 1 I show these records in the results.

Comment: when you said you partition by the two parts instead, after you subject the result-set of tickers_table to group by first(ticker), do you then subject the original result-set or the grouped-by set to be grouped by second(ticker)? i guess if I subject the result set to "partition by" two separate fields, i can get it cos it's the same as group by field A, then field B.  But in your instance, they are the same field.

Comment: To make this clear first: The query works and you try to understand why. Correct? Then as to grouping/partitioning: This is not like order by where you order by one column and inside that order you sort by the second one and so on. `GROUP BY` and `PARTITION BY` consider the combination of all fields (no matter in what order!) a group.

Comment: So take the table with the sample data you posted, draw a new column, put in that column what the partition is (which is 123,C1 for the first row, 123,C1 for the second, 124,C2 for the third, and so on. Then draw another column. Count the rows that have the same partition. That is 2 for the first row, 2 for the second (as both are in the same partition), 2 for the third and so on. This is what my `count(*) over (partition by ...)` expression does.

Comment: HI, i think i get it.. your query is working and good. note to myself: for each row, for each combintation of '123' and 'CS' (C1') find the count in the whole table.